# Организовать алгоритм обработки исключений в сетевой библиотеке

Tags: c#, исключения

В следствии обстоятельств пришлось собрать собственную библиотеку для работа с Http  на основе tcp клиента. Далее последовала реализация протоколов для прокси (Https, Socks4\5) и появилась следующая проблема. Есть куча мест, в которых может появится исключение. Читаю\пишу в стрим - может быть исключение, коннект с tcp клиенту - исключение, что-то с прокси сервером или некорректный ответ от него - исключение. Сначала я сделал своё единое исключение и просто, перехватывая другие, выкидывал его. А так как кол-во запросов идёт большое, ловить и выкидывать новое исключение стоит достаточно много ресурсов ( в некоторых случаях нагрузка на цп прыгает от 50 до 90 процентов, что не приемлемо ). Из этого возник вопрос, каким образом организовать обработку множества разнотипных исключений с минимальными затратами ресурсов пк и при этом удобством использования конечного пользователя данной библиотеки?

Comment: как пользователь разных библиотек, я бы предпочел получить документацию к методам, с перечислением кейсов, при которых возникает тот или иной тип исключения и самостоятельно ловить оригинальные типы исключений по необходимости. ИМХО, новый тип исключений реально нужен достаточно редко (в моей практике пока только один случай, не считая академических экспериментов).

Comment: @rdorn Т.е по факту полностью убрать трай-кетчи с проблемных мест и оставить это на пользователе предварительно описав возможные исключения? (Под проблемными местами я подразумеваю исключения не зависящие от кода, а связанные с сетевыми проблемами по типу невалидной прокси)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514850/198316. В целом да, у вас же библиотека, а не законченное приложение. Библиотека должна обрабатывать только те исключения, с которыми знает что делать и как исправить ситуацию. Даже решение о логировании должен принимать конечный пользователь. Разумеется, со мной могут не согласиться другие участники =)